# Submit a form in angular 2 from a component inside ngAfterViewInit()

Tags: html, forms, angular, typescript

I am trying to submit a form in angular 2 from a component after it is loaded and initialised using onInit();

Below is my code for the same

app.component.html

```
<form #myForm class="hidden" name="myForm" action="{{formLink}}" method="post">
  <input class="hidden" type="text" id="token" name="token" value="{{token}}" />
  <input class="btn btn-primary pull-right hidden" #submitmyForm id="submitmyForm" type="submit" value="Submit"
  />
</form>
```

app.component.ts

```
@ViewChild('myForm') myForm: NgForm;
  @ViewChild('submitmyForm') submitmyForm: ElementRef;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.articleLink = localStorage.getItem('articleLink'); 
  }
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const event = new MouseEvent('click', { bubbles: true });
    this.renderer.invokeElementMethod(
      this.submitmyForm.nativeElement, 'dispatchEvent', [event]);// Dosent Work
    this.submitmyForm.nativeElement.click();//Dosent Work   
}
```

Comment: You can use this for submitting form `<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #heroForm="ngForm">` more info here https://angular.io/guide/forms

Comment: Thanks for the replay @onetwo12 : But I need to submit the form as soon as the component is loaded I need options to do that,
 however (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" will need a click event to be triggered from the form side and as u can see in my code i am hiding the form from the user and directly submiting the once once the user visits the link i.e. component